# Content not found error after clicking on game request notification on facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-app-requests

I have created a game in android and iOS. I have created an app on facebook with category as GAME.

I am able to send requests to facebook friends by using FBSDKGameRequestDialog.

But when i click on the notification received, it gives me the following error, instead of redirecting to the playstore.

[image: See this image for reference]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, its working now. May be some facebook bug which they fixed and its working without any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this exact message until I turned on deep-linking in the Facebook dev console > settings > basic page. Even then it took a day or so before Facebook cache was cleared and it began working.